# Preparing computer to learn System Calls and Linux kernel modules

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, system-calls, kernel-module

I want to begin my Linux Kernel Programming by making modules and system calls. But i don't want to play with my existing system. I have downloaded a 2.6 kernel for experiment purposes but i don't know how to use it for my experiments. Please help.

1) Where should i make System Calls (i mean which kernel)? And how to set it up ?

2) A good place to learn System Calls for a beginner like me ?

(update) - Can i use earlier versions of Linux Kernel (At boot up it shows me previous versions).

Answer (score 2):

Install VirtualBox, install a Linux distribution in a VM, get it set up, shut it down (not suspended), copy it somewhere so you can recover when you trash it/render it unbootable.  Do your experimentation in the VM.

What kernel to use doesn't really matter that much; you'll do better using one that matches your available userspace (and particularly `glibc`) though, which is why it's better to pick a distribution than a kernel version.

Comment: I should also mention that I typically keep my source files in an NFS mount on the host, so they are safe if I trash the VM.

Comment: Please suggest some other way. I only have 64-bit Ubuntu but my processor doesn't support VT.